# Transform POST Data Before Persisting

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am writing an API with TastyPie that a Django application will hit.  One of the POST endpoints must validate data before inserting into the db.  The process includes checking a record in another table with a value in the POST data.

How do I apply business logic before inserting the POST data?  If an insert is not deemed viable, how do I send a custom exception to the client?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html#cleaneddataformvalidation), extend the `CleanedDataFormValidation` class and override the `is_valid` method with your business logic. Return `form.errors` if there are errors ([official tastypie usage](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/604e4ac97046773625c99ae43dd1c1df1b4d39af/tastypie/validation.py#L93)).